# AngularJS and IFrame srcdoc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I parsed a bunch of email messages from a server, and I would now like to display them on a webpage. I got their HTML contents and I figured an IFrame was the easiest way to show the emails as they were meant to be shown.

However,

```
<iframe srcdoc="{{ email.html }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Gives me the following AngularJS error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ email.html }}
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
```

I have been searching for a way to do this, tried disabling $sce as a test, but that didn't work either. It's just a test project and the data I'm getting is safe, I just need it for a POC.

I did this now in my controller:

```
var iframeDocument = document.querySelector('#myiframe').contentWindow.document;
var content = $scope.email.html;
iframeDocument.open('text/html', 'replace');
iframeDocument.write(content);
iframeDocument.close();
```

That works, but I'd still prefer to do it through data-binding, if there's a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @dandavis An HTML document containing the actual email contents

Comment: trying turning the doc into a string first, eventually setting the srcDoc to the html string.

Comment: @dandavis Could you elaborate? The email contents is one large HTML string. I just want to dump the whole email in an IFrame but Angular won't let me. I tried something like this: `$('#myiframe').attr('srcdoc', $scope.email.html);` but that didn't really work out either.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think Angular supports this currently. I believe you'd need to do `$scope.emailHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.email.html)`, but there is no `ng-srcdoc-bind-html` which I think is the other piece of this puzzle (checkout `ng-bind-html`)

Comment: Another possibility is to disable SCE, See this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#example_can-i-disable-sce-completely

Answer (score 8):

Add a filter to make a value trusted:

```
angular.module('app').filter('toTrusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

And then apply the filter:

```
<iframe srcdoc="{{email.html | toTrusted}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/2bvktbLr/1/

Answer (score 2):

try to add ***ngSanitize*** as a dependency in your app.

here your have more information : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: This helped me.  I already had angular-sanitize.js referenced from my index.html, but I needed to add it as a dependency: angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);